# Can I have multiple deployed Sunderers?

Tags: planetside-2

Is there some kind of vehicle limit ? Or can I surround an enemy base with spawn points ?

Comment: Unless the game has changed since I last played it, yes, theoretically you could do so. It's not smart, but you could do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only have one vehicle spawned at a time, however, multiple people can spawn Sunderers and spread them out enough to effectively surround a base with spawn points.

When a Sunderer is deployed, another Sunderer cannot deploy nearby. This is signified by the bubble around the Sund when driving your own.

Comment: So I tested and looks like after spawning a second vehicle the old one will despawn within a minute or so, deployed or not doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

You can spawn a sunderer, park it next to the vehicle spawn pad, spawn a second sunderer, get back into the first one. You will now own the second sunderer, but he able to drive the first one,  park it,  deploy it etc. **Anyone who gets in the first sunderer will now own it.**  So while it is technically possible to have two in operation, it's not actually that useful